# What is the correct way to nest exceptions? - Using Delphi

Tags: delphi, exception

Assume I have three (or more) procedures, some of which call each other, as shown below, any one of which can fail.

If any one of them do fail I want the 'main' program to immediately log the failure and terminate the program.

What is the correct syntax to use in Delphi to 'pass back' an exception to each preceeding procedure call?

Even better if someone can help me to get the main program's Try/except block to identify which bit failed!

Sample pseudo code of the three procedures and the main program might look like below.

(I think I understand the principle, something to do with 'raise',  but would like some help with the actual syntax and what code I should use)

```
//////////////////////////////////////
Procedure DoProcA
begin
try
   begin
   {stuff};  //stuff that might fall
   end;
except
 on E : Exception do 
     begin 
     LogError ('error in A'); 
     end  //on E
end;//try

 //////////////////////////////////////

Procedure DoProcB
begin
try
  begin 
  Do ProcC;  //another proc that might fail
  {other stuff}
  end;
except
 on E : Exception do
     begin
     LogError ('error in B');
     end  //on E
end;//try

 //////////////////////////////////////

Procedure DoProcC
begin
try
  begin 
  {Do stuff}  //even more stuf fthat might fail
  end;
except
 on E : Exception do
     begin
     LogError ('error in C');
     end  //on E
end;//try

 //////////////////////////////////////

 //Main programo
 begin 
 try
    DoProcA;
    DoProcB;
    {other stuff}
 except
   {here I want to be able to do something like
    if failure of A, B or C then
       begin      
       LogError ('Failure somewhere in A, B or C');
       application.terminate;
       end;}
 end; //try
 end.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have each function **re-raise** the caught exception after logging it, eg:

```
Procedure DoProcA;
begin
  try
    {stuff};  //stuff that might fall
  except
    on E : Exception do 
    begin 
      LogError ('error in A'); 
      raise; // <-- here
    end;
  end;
end;

Procedure DoProcB;
begin
  try
    DoProcC;  //another proc that might fail
    {other stuff}
  except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      LogError ('error in B');
      raise; // <-- here
    end;
  end;
end;

Procedure DoProcC;
begin
  try
    {Do stuff}  //even more stuff that might fail
  except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      LogError ('error in C');
      raise; // <-- here
    end;
  end;
end;

begin 
  try
    DoProcA;
    DoProcB;
    {other stuff}
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      LogError ('Failure somewhere in A, B or C');
      //Application.Terminate; // this is not useful unless Application.Run is called first
    end;
  end;
end.
```

If you want the main procedure to identify WHICH function failed, you need to pass that information down the exception chain, eg:

```
type
  MyException = class(Exception)
  public
    WhichFunc: String;
    constructor CreateWithFunc(const AWhichFunc, AMessage: String);
  end;

constructor MyException.CreateWithFunc(const AWhichFunc, AMessage: String);
begin
  inherited Create(AMessage);
  WhichFunc := AWhichFunc;
end;

Procedure DoProcA;
begin
  try
    {stuff};  //stuff that might fall
  except
    on E : Exception do 
    begin 
      raise MyException.CreateWithFunc('DoProcA', E.Message); // <-- here
    end;
  end;
end;

Procedure DoProcB;
begin
  try
    DoProcC;  //another proc that might fail
    {other stuff}
  except
    on E : MyException do
    begin
      raise; // <-- here
    end;
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      raise MyException.CreateWithFunc('DoProcB', E.Message); // <-- here
    end;
  end;
end;

Procedure DoProcC;
begin
  try
    {Do stuff}  //even more stuff that might fail
  except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      raise MyException.CreateWithFunc('DoProcC', E.Message); // <-- here
    end;
  end;
end;

begin 
  try
    DoProcA;
    DoProcB;
    {other stuff}
  except
    on E: MyException do
    begin
      LogError ('Failure in ' + E.WhichFunc + ': ' + E.Message);
    end;
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      LogError ('Failure somewhere else: ' + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Or:

```
type
  MyException = class(Exception)
  public
    WhichFunc: String;
    constructor CreateWithFunc(const AWhichFunc, AMessage: String);
  end;

constructor MyException.CreateWithFunc(const AWhichFunc, AMessage: String);
begin
  inherited Create(AMessage);
  WhichFunc := AWhichFunc;
end;

Procedure DoProcA;
begin
  try
    {stuff};  //stuff that might fall
  except
    on E : Exception do 
    begin 
      raise MyException.CreateWithFunc('DoProcA', E.Message); // <-- here
    end;
  end;
end;

Procedure DoProcB;
begin
  try
    DoProcC;  //another proc that might fail
    {other stuff}
  except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      Exception.RaiseOuterException(MyException.CreateWithFunc('DoProcB', E.Message)); // <-- here
    end;
  end;
end;

Procedure DoProcC;
begin
  try
    {Do stuff}  //even more stuff that might fail
  except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      raise MyException.CreateWithFunc('DoProcC', E.Message); // <-- here
    end;
  end;
end;

var
  Ex: Exception;
begin 
  try
    DoProcA;
    DoProcB;
    {other stuff}
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Ex := E;
      repeat
        if Ex is MyException then
          LogError ('Failure in ' + MyException(Ex).WhichFunc + ': ' + Ex.Message)
        else
          LogError ('Failure somewhere else: ' + Ex.Message);
        Ex := Ex.InnerException;
      until Ex = nil;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: The application.terminate is there because the code where all this is could be run either manually or when the program is called via a scheduled job by passing a parameter. (I test if this is the case and only terminate if it is). At the moment I am having problems because if an exception happens the program could hang and then the next time the scheduler tries to run the job that fails as the job is already running. So the idea is to ensure that if it is being run with a command line parameter then ANY exception causes the program to terminate correctly and ideally, log why it failed.

Comment: `Application.Terminate()` merely posts a `WM_QUIT` message to the calling thread's message queue.  `Application.Run()` runs the actual message loop. If you do not call `Application.Run()`, or otherwise run your own message loop, `Application.Terminate()` is useless. Just exit from the main `begin/end.` block to terminate the process.  And exceptions themselves do not cause hangs. Your code would have to be doing something in response to a caught exception in order to hang, such as displaying a modal popup message box that the user has to (but not be able to) dismiss.

Comment: Thanks Remy, very useful stuff - and a few pointers to where my program could be failing. I do indeed have several messages to show exceptions to an interactive user. I bet one of those is showing when its run as a scheduled job. Difficult to know who to award the answer to, you or David as you are both always very helpful. In this case, as David says himself, he gave me very useful advice but you answered the question directly so I guess the winner has to be Remy for actually answering the question. Thanks to both.

Comment: `Exception.ToString` method iterates through inner exceptions, it can be useful instead of hand-written loop. Sadly it not add extra info like `WhichFunc` or even `Exception.ClassName`.

Comment: And much mo sad, `Exception.RaiseOuterException` do not used internally on any libraries `raise` statements, so nested exception masked each other often enough ((

Answer (score 9):

The best way to deal with this is to remove all of these exception handlers. Use an library like madExcept, EurekaLog, JCL Debug etc. to log any exceptions that make it all the way back to the top level exception handler.

It's simply untenable for you to attempt to add an exception handler to each and every function in your program. That's not at all how exceptions are meant to be used. As a broad rule, you should regard exceptions as things that should not be caught. They represent exceptional behaviour, and as such, it is usually the case that the function where they are raised does not know how to deal with them.

So, stop trying to handle exceptions. Don't handle them, as a guiding principle. If they make it all the way to the top level exception handler, deal with them there. And if you use one of the libraries mentioned above you will be able to obtain rich debugging information to help you understand why the exception was raised in the first place.

Comment: @David, Please could you explain what you mean? Do you mean just have the try except block in the Main program and nowhere else?  I value comments from yourself and Remy as you both know what you are talking about but you seem to differ in opionion on this one

Comment: You should only **handle** an exception if you **really can handle** it. Do not implement a blind catch all exceptions.

Comment: @Sir Rufo. I don't really follow. Are you suggesting that I use David's solution or Remy's then? Which, in your view, uses a catch all?

Comment: I mean that you remove all exception handlers in your program. Nobody sane writes code which adds a try except to every single method of the program. Instead don't handle any exceptions other than ones that you can deal with. And let an bespoke exception logging tool gather the information you need. That way you get the information without destroying your code.

Comment: And I doubt that Remy and I differ in opinion. He was answering your question directly. I was offering advice on how to solve the problem a better way. Both are valid.

Comment: Ok I understand what you are saying about the tool, although they are expensive (I'd prefer not to use JCL stuff) and I'm still not clear how I would gracefully terminate the program after an exception (if it is being run with a command line parameter, its not important otherwise)

Comment: Ok Point taken about you and Remy!

Comment: An exception logger lets you run code in its top level exception handler. Termination can be done. madExcept is free for non commercial projects and cheap for commercial projects.

Comment: The other problem with you approach is that you won't catch exceptions raised in RTL code at the point they are raised. Only at the point you first catch them. But frankly, putting an exception handler in every function is nothing short of crazy.

Comment: This advice sadly does not works at all (((
May be in unicorn and pink ponies world it will, but not in ours.
Usually we need much more precise and detailed information about exception, so need enrich exceptions with context information while it raises trough call stack. Write it into log, into Exception object itself, and so on.

Comment: @Nashev works fine here

Answer (score 4):

Developers from other languages spend a lot of time and energy worrying about "unhandled exceptions" but in a typical Delphi forms application, if you look at the code behind Application.Run you will see that all exceptions will get handled if you let them bubble all the way to the top. (Which is the preferred behaviour, unless you have good reason to interfere)

Quite often, it is a good idea to add more information to the exception, and then re-raise it, ie. let it go. Something went wrong, your calling function needs to know, and that is the purpose of an exception in the first place.

If you are wanting to log each and every error, then a good place to do that would be in the Application.OnException event. NB. your example is a DOS style command line application, not a typical Delphi Windows forms application, not sure if that is what you intended. If this was just to try keep the example simple, you have actually created more work for yourself, as you don't have access to the Application object and all the functionality that goes with that.

Eg.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnException := AppException;
end;

procedure TForm1.AppException(Sender: TObject; E: Exception);
begin
  if RunningInAutomationMode then
    begin
      LogError(E.Message);
      Application.Terminate;
    end
  else
    Application.ShowException(E);

end;
```

To answer your question directly though:

```
Procedure DoProcA;
begin
  try
    {stuff};  //stuff that might fall
  except
    on E : Exception do 
    begin 
      //LogError ('error in A');  will get logged later, don't want to log twice
      E.Message := 'The following error occurred while trying to do whatzit to a whozit: '+E.Message;
      raise; 
    end;
  end;
end;

Procedure DoProcB;
begin
  try
    DoProcC;  //another proc that might fail
    {other stuff}
  except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      //LogError ('error in B');
      E.Message := E.Message + ' (Proc B)';
      raise; 
    end;
  end;
end;

Procedure DoProcC;
begin
  try
    {Do stuff}  //even more stuff that might fail
  except
     on E : Exception do
    begin
      //LogError ('error in C');
      E.Message := 'The following error occurred during procedure C: '+E.Message;
      raise; //Note: do not use raise Exception.Create(E.Message); as you will then lose the exception's type, which can be very useful information to have
    end;
  end;
end;

begin
   try
     DoProcA;
     DoProcB;
     {other stuff}
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      LogError (E.Message); //this will end up logging all the exceptions, no mater which procedure they occurred in
      //Exception has not been re-raised, so code will continue from this point
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

{Some more code} //Called exit above, so that this code won't get called, although it is unlikely you'll have more code outside the try..except block

end.
```

Comment: Yes the code was simplified for this forum. It is actualy in the OnShow event of the main form. I have a menu option to re-populate one database from another external one, download stuff from an online server, do lots of maths and save summaries in my database. Any error messages here are shown to the user.  However, the program can also be called by a scheduler with a command line parameter to do all this work overnight. I detect this early in OnShow and in that case I need this section of code to be bomb proof, log any errors so I know where it went wrong and always shut down gracefully.

Comment: Okay, then you just need to log the error in the Application.OnException event, that's all, nowhere else. I have added an example on using Application.OnException to my original answer.

Comment: The example code is a bit unclear - sometimes it uses `E.Message := E.Message + ` and sometimes E.Message := 'some value'` which - depending on the call tree - would override the existing information. I guess it would be better to have a string list or to add the complete data of the 'inner' exception in the next higher level exception.

Comment: Hi mjn, in all 3 procedures, DoProcA, DoProcB and DoProcC I have kept the original message. I just put the message in DoProcB at the front, simply to show that you have the flexibility to do what you like. In real life, I would have chosen to be more consistent though, and format them in a similar way.

Comment: If you had more information to add to the exception, and especially if you are raising the exception in your procedure for the first time - not trapping someone else's - you should consider creating and raising your own exception type, but that is beyond the scope of the original question.