# Raising exceptions is not showing messages

Tags: delphi, exception

I am struggling with something I have always perceived as something straightforward, but apparently I am missing something in this case.

I am using Delphi Seattle.

In part of my program I have a certain main calculation (a loop) that repeatedly calls a sub-calculation.  In certain cases the sub-calculation result will go towards infinity and cause a floating point overflow exception.  I cannot predict this, nor can I define / trap an acceptable maximum value (depends on case) so I need to trap the overflow exception, notify the user and abort the calculation.

I have simplified this calculation to the following example program.  The code itself is nonsense of course but the point is to force an overflow exception in a similar program structure as my real application.

```
  type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    function MainCalculation: boolean;
    function SubCalculation(AFloatingPoint: Double): Double;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

.........

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      if MainCalculation then
        ShowMessage('Calculation succeeded.')
      else
        ShowMessage('Calculation failed.');
    end;

    function TForm1.MainCalculation: boolean;
    var
      ii: Integer;
      dd: Double;
    begin
      try
        dd := 1E200;
        for ii := 1 to 100 do
          dd := dd * SubCalculation(dd);
      except
        raise Exception.Create('Error in main calculation.');
      end;
    end;

    function TForm1.SubCalculation(AFloatingPoint: Double): Double;
    begin
      try
        result := Power(AFloatingPoint, AFloatingPoint);
      except
        raise Exception.Create('Error in sub-calculation.');
      end;
    end;
```

Running from the debugger, I get three Debugger Exception Notifications:

1. Exception class $C0000091 (floating point overflow)
2. Exception in sub-calculation
3. Exception in main calculation

However, only the last one is shown to the user as an exception.

In my real application it's even worse.  When I run the application and the overflow exception occurs, nothing is shown to the user and the (main) calculation just aborts with partial results.

Can anybody explain to me why I don't get the two exceptions raised (as I would expect)?  Is there a specific setting somewhere that causes the overflow exception to be treated different?  Any suggestion to help me forward will be highly appreciated.  Of course, I'll be more than happy to provide additional details, should this be required.

Thanks in advance!
Mark

Comment: The end user only sees the last raised excpetion, because the previous ones where "handled" in the except blocks. Maybe in your real life application, there is an try-except block with an empty or non-raising except part. In general handling exceptions indiscriminatly is rarely a good idea - either only stop specific excpetions or at least keep all exception information when sucking it up and raising your own.

Comment: could you provide a simplified version of your real code. I mean the count of how many times you are using the try-except block and how they are implemented.

Comment: the raise line in the exception part of sub-calculation method is not shown because it is treated in the main-calculation method which will show the main-calculation method message instead. I guess that in your real life code their is another try-except block that is prohibiting the last message to be shown thus you need to provide more info

Comment: I found the problem thanks to @SebastianProske.  I kind of embarrassed to admit I missed the obvious; there's another try..except one level 'above' the main calculation where nothing was raised - only result set to false.  However, it is of interest to me raise the 'embedded' exceptions to the user to provide a clue what went wrong and why the calculation was aborted.  Of course I can display a message instead, but the calculation are in a 'non-visual' unit.  Is there a way to force raising the inner exceptions?

Comment: Look at Application.ShowException. It's what calls MessageBox with the exception message. If someone does not show the message, no message is shown. You need to show yourself what you need to show if you don't leave it to the Application.

Comment: @user8425066 Exceptions raise as far as you let them.  If you don't want to handle them at a lower level then don't.  If you need to clean up after yourself just use `try/finally` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to nest exceptions? - Using Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209877/what-is-the-correct-way-to-nest-exceptions-using-delphi)

Comment: Don't handle exceptions at all and everything will be good

Comment: FWIW I don't think this question is a duplicate of the mentioned one. I think the problem here is a misconception of what an exception is. It's not an error message displayed to the user, it's an exceptional condition which interrupts the execution of code. The question would grant a conceptual explanation rather than a general guideline.

Comment: I don't think there' a misunderstanding on the concept of what an exception is. It's merely that raising a standard Exception (i. e. not an EMyCustomException) with a specific message is not shown to the end-user once it's "nested".

Comment: I.e. the ability to use a custom message (parameter for create) seems to imply that something will show something to the end-user.

Comment: @user8425066 I'm not sure how it implies that.  `ShowMessage`, for example, implies that it will show a message.  If you want to show a message then show a message - don't use unhandled exceptions as a message box.  Exceptions are usually something you would *log* rather than *show the user*

Comment: @user8425066 btw Your question has absolutely nothing to do with "floating point" or even overflows for that matter. That's just what you're using to trigger the first exception in the call chain. You would have the same confusion regardless what/how the exception is triggered. You could make your test code much simpler and a lot clearer by simply calling `raise Exception.Create('What happens now?');` I'll edit your question slightly to get rid of the irrelevant fluff.

Comment: @user8425066 The documentation you're looking for is there. But sometimes you need to know what to look for... http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.AppEvnts.TCustomApplicationEvents.OnException and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/OnException_(Delphi)

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Exceptions_(Delphi)#Nested_Exceptions

Answer (score 1):

> I don't think there' a misunderstanding on the concept of what an exception is. It's merely that raising a standard Exception (i. e. not an EMyCustomException) with a specific message is not shown to the end-user once it's "nested".

You do have a misunderstanding of some aspects of exceptions. I suspect you correctly understand how they affect code-flow (an area most people struggle with). But any expectation that they will show messages indicates a huge misunderstanding.

Note that it would be fundamentally incorrect for exceptions to in any way automatically display the exception message because if the app runs on an unattended server, the last thing you want is dialogs popping up on screen waiting for a non-existent user to close them.

Even on a front-end, it would be a ***horrible*** user experience to display a long chain of exception messages for each and every negative consequence side-effect you choose to report in a *boiler-plate* (DRY violating) `try...except` block.

***The only time any exception message will be displayed is when code explicitly calls something to do so***

E.g.: `ShowMessage(SomeException.Message);`
or `Application.ShowException(SomeException.Message);`

You also asked:

> but if "raise Exception.Create..." is not meant to display anything, then why does the outer level?

I can see why you might think that; but this is exactly the misunderstanding referred to earlier...

The outer level `raise Exception.Create('Some Message');` **does NOT** display any message. The Delphi framework has its own `try...except` block which catches the outer level exception, and by *default* will show the message and class of the exception. You could override the default handler to display a different message or use a different dialog, or not display anything, and simply log the message.

As an exercise, you may want to step through vcl/rtl code using a debugger to see this in action. The source code that ships with Delphi may seem intimidating, but studying that code is an excellent way to learn.

#### Suggested further reading

- [RAD Studio Exceptions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Exceptions_(Delphi)#Nested_Exceptions) (link goes directly to Nested Exceptions; but read the whole page)
- [TApplication.OnException](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.OnException) (a similar feature exists for FMX)
- [TCustomApplicationEvents.OnException](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.AppEvnts.TCustomApplicationEvents.OnException)

---

Obviously and understandably you have a concern about tracking information at each exception handler. This is good; but the way you're trying to go about it is flawed. I suggest you read up on the following poss-dups:

[How should I re-raise a Delphi exception after logging it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2923230/224704)
[What is the correct way to nest exceptions? - Using Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34209877/224704)

I also recommend you consider using an exception handling framework. I'm not sure of the current state of the following, but they're all worth investigating:

- Mad Except
- Exceptional Magic
- Eureka
- Jcl Debug

Note that tools like those above are able to generate a call-stack which provides a full chain of calls leading to the trigger exception. Combine this with general trace logging and you have a powerful set of tools to fully investigate most typical errors.

In general you don't want to be writing a large number of `try...except` blocks. They really should be the (ahem) "***exception*** to the rule".

---

***Side note***: Acknowledging your code is merely a sample...

I must point out that as it stands, your question code is seriously flawed. You fail to guarantee the `Result` of `MainCalculation` will be initialised no matter **if/where** an exception might occur and whether or not it's swallowed. You need to be very careful of this to avoid returning the wrong value to callers such as `ButtonClick`.

The last thing you want is callers incorrectly assuming a failed calculation succeeded or vice-versa. (This is a benefit of the structured exception model and not writing lots of exception handlers.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `sysUtils.abort("silent exception")`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.